# Access to submodules is not possible ( Not a git repository)

Tags: git, git-submodules

I wan to add the repositories of a project to my project as submodules.  The link of the repositories can be found in the .gitmodules.

I copied the links to clone the repositories including their submodules.

```
:~$ git clone --recursive [URL to Git repo]
```

After this I wanted to load the cloned submodules:

```
:~$ git submodule update --init –recursive
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

**fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git**

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The directory you're in isn't a repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- change directory *into the repo* you just cloned, and
- use `--recursive` with two dashes.

`git clone` is, as far as I know, the only git command that works if you're not already in a git repository.